# Hacking through a firewall

Tags: ddos

couldn't you DDOS attack an firewall somehow so that it would shutdown and you could access the computer?

Comment: Please read the [about] page for guidance on how to ask questions appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 4):

A firewall that is overloaded fails closed: it stops mapping or accepting connections as it fails to handle the load.